# What does constant along characteristic mean

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, parabolic-pde, pseudo-differential-operators

When we have linear or quasilinear first order pde

$$ a(x,y,u) u_x + b(x,y,u) u_y = c(x,y,u) $$

And suppose we have found characteristics with prescribed Cauchy data $u |_{\text{curve}} = \phi$

I always see on my notes that the solution $u$ is always constant on the characteristics curves. What do they really mean by that? What is the geometric intuition ..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, for this equation you get the system 
$$\dot x=a(x,y,u),\\\dot y=b(x,y,u),\\\dot u=c(x,y,u)$$ which in general leads to a non-constant $u$. $u$ is only constant along characteristics if $c=0$. As the solution surface is a family of curves with a one-dimensional cross-section, the 3 integration constants of the system depend on only one parameter, which allows to incorporate the initial conditions.

Comment: Im having hard time understanding the geometry. Can you give me some intuitions?

Comment: You look at $z(t)=u(x(t),y(t))$ for any differentiable functions $x,y$. Then $\dot z=u_x\dot x+u_y\dot y$. Now if $\dot x=a$ and $\dot y=b$ as (not so) arbitrary restriction, $\dot z=c$ follows from the PDE. // $z=u(x,y)$ as surface is two-dimensional. So if the curve parameter of the characteristics is one dimension, only one other dimension remains.