# Why are first integrals constant along characteristic curves?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

Why are first integrals constant along characteristic curves? My lecturer in a PDE course seems to be using this fact. I found a nice explanation of what a first integral is here: [Why are they called "first integrals"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3203855/why-are-they-called-first-integrals). However, I am unable to connect this with the concept of a characteristic, or understand why first integrals are constant along characteristics. For context, this was used in explaining "alternative method of solution using characteristics", that is constructing a family of characteristic curves using two linearly independent first integrals of a pde.

Maybe this is relevant: [What does constant along characteristic mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3110669/what-does-constant-along-characteristic-mean), but I don't see how.

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a specific example? It's not clear (to me at least) exactly what you're referring to. Maybe the best thing would be to actually ask the lecturer?

Answer (score 1):

The first integral of system of ODEs is such a function $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ that is constant along any solution of system, i.e $f(x(t)) = const$.

Intersection of surfaces $\phi_1(x_1,...,x_n)=C_1, ..., \phi_n(x_1,...,x_n)=C_n$ defined by first integrals determines a family of surfaces where solution of system lies

[image: The first integral of]

The method of characteristics reduces a problem of solving PDE to a system of ODEs, a general solution is said to be constant along characteristics curves so it's some arbitrary function of first integrals:
$$\Phi(\phi_1(x_1,...,x_n),...,\phi_n(x_1,...,x_n)) = 0$$